# can't import keras.layers.Merge

Tags: python, keras

I want to merge two LSTM models in Keras. I have seen many examples of importing Merge as:

```
from keras.layers import Merge
```

When I do this, I get an import error.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Merge'.`

Has there been some refactor and now Merge is elsewhere?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of keras 2, the module `keras.layers.merge` doesn't have a generic public `Merge`-Layer. Instead you are supposed to import the subclasses like `keras.layers.Add` or `keras.layers.Concatenate` etc. directly (or their functional interfaces with the same names lowercase: `keras.layers.add`, `keras.layers.concatenate` etc.).

See what types of merging layers exist in the [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)

**Edit**: `tf.keras.layers.Add` etc. would now be the correct import path using [`tf.keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) inside tensorflow - since [keras 2.3.0](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0) (Sep 2019), this is the developer's official recommendation:

> This is also the last major release of multi-backend Keras. Going forward, we recommend that users consider switching their Keras code to tf.keras in TensorFlow 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Activation, Merge, Concatenate,Input
```

write to below code:only change small letter(merge)

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Activation, merge, Concatenate,Input
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause : case sensitive
change it
`from keras.layers import Merge`
to
`from keras.layers import merge`