# Does keras have a pretrained AlexNet like VGG19?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pre-trained-model, vgg-net

If I want to use pretrained VGG19 network, I can simply do

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
VGG19(weights='imagenet')
```

Is there a similar implementation for `AlexNet` in keras or any other library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone comes here for a solution,
I found a pretrained alex net from PyTorch [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html)

```
import torchvision.models as models
alexnet_model = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find pretrained `AlexNet` model for `keras` [here](https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras#get-the-weights-of-the-pre-trained-networks).

Comment: Its not working. In `convnets-keras/convnetskeras/customlayers.py` it uses `from keras.layers.core import Merge` which has been removed now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031519/cant-import-keras-layers-merge