# Cannot `import name '_Merge' from 'keras.layers.merge`' in Tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-2

I am trying to run the following code on an environment which has Tensorflow 2 installed:

```
from keras.layers.merge import _Merge

class RandomWeightedAverage(_Merge):
"""Provides a (random) weighted average between real and generated image samples"""
def _merge_function(self, inputs):
    global batch_size
    alpha = K.random_uniform((batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
    return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_Merge' from 'keras.layers.merge'

How should I modify the code to be compatible with Tensorflow2?

Comment: Try using [layers-concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate)

Comment: @Frightera Would you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Use `from keras.layers import merge`. Regarding layers-cancatenate take a look at similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031648/14290244). Thanks!